# Android strange Debug Log Message

Tags: java, android, logging, native, db4o

I am using db40 in my Android App. If I want to store a Notification, they are stored, but after that my App crashes with this strange Message:

```
        08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961): Build fingerprint: 'google/soju/crespo:2.3.4/GRJ22/121341:user/release-keys'
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961): pid: 7950, tid: 7951  >>> de.eos.uptrade.android.fahrinfo <<<
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  r0 00000001  r1 40697d88  r2 42191684  r3 0000000c
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  r4 40697d88  r5 00000000  r6 ad386934  r7 00115998
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  r8 100ffad0  r9 43c84fa4  10 43c84f8c  fp 800a5368
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  ip ad34dbcd  sp 100ffab8  lr 80049111  pc ad34dbee  cpsr 20000030
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d0  4050ec404050ec00  d1  002e0070007000c0
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d2  0069007400630007  d3  0079007400690000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d4  00300033002a4478  d5  0033002c00310030
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d6  002c003200300030  d7  0037003000300031
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d16 00016f1800000001  d17 3ff0000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    08-24 13:58:03.753: INFO/DEBUG(7961):  scr 80000012
    08-24 13:58:03.824: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #00  pc 0004dbee  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    08-24 13:58:03.828: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #01  pc 00017e34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.832: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #02  pc 0004968c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.832: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #03  pc 0001d034  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.832: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #04  pc 000220e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.832: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #05  pc 00020fdc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.835: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #06  pc 0005fc40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.835: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #07  pc 0005fe54  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.835: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #08  pc 00055fec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.835: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #09  pc 00056068  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.839: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #10  pc 000561fa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.839: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #11  pc 000540ce  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.839: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #12  pc 000118e4  /system/lib/libc.so
    08-24 13:58:03.839: INFO/DEBUG(7961):          #13  pc 000114b0  /system/lib/libc.so
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): code around pc:
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): ad34dbcc 41f0e92d 460c4e0d 447e4607 f7e66a72 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): ad34dbdc 6a72f9f3 23004621 46384605 fc88f7f4 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): ad34dbec 682b4621 0c0cf853 f7d31828 f7d5ec5e 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): ad34dbfc f7d5e98e e8bde992 bf0081f0 00038d5a 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): ad34dc0c f7d5b510 f7d5e984 bd10e98e 4614b510 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): code around lr:
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): 800490f0 4630460c 461f2101 fe02f009 f01368eb 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): 80049100 692b0f40 50e7d0ff 21074630 fdf8f009 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): 80049110 81f0e8bd 41f0e92d 46156906 4630460c 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): 80049120 461f2101 fdecf009 f01368eb 692b0f40 
    08-24 13:58:03.843: INFO/DEBUG(7961): 80049130 50e7d0ff 21074630 fde2f009 81f0e8bd 
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961): stack:
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa78  00000001  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa7c  100ffaf0  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa80  421916d4  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa84  421916d4  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa88  40697d88  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa8c  42191684  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa90  0011f648  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa94  80049111  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa98  800490e9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffa9c  00000000  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffaa0  ad386934  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffaa4  00115998  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffaa8  100ffad0  
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffaac  ad342507  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    08-24 13:58:03.847: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffab0  df002777  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffab4  e3a070ad  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961): #00 100ffab8  100ffaf0  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffabc  00000000  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffac0  100ffb70  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffac4  43c84fac  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffac8  100ffad0  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffacc  80017e38  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961): #01 100ffad0  0011f648  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffad4  00000001  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffad8  100ffb70  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffadc  43c84fa0  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffae0  421916d4  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffae4  0011f648  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffae8  100ffaf0  
    08-24 13:58:03.851: INFO/DEBUG(7961):     100ffaec  8004968f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-24 13:58:04.144: INFO/BootReceiver(115): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    08-24 13:58:04.175: INFO/DEBUG(7961): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
    08-24 13:58:04.195: INFO/DEBUG(7972): debuggerd: Apr 22 2011 14:06:04
```

I can store other Objects without this error, so I assume It's not db4o's fault.
Im Using a Samsung Nexus 2 with Android 2.1 as my build target.
  Any Ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something crashed the dalvik virtual machine and the *zombie* message just tells us, that the debugger stopped to allow android to remove the zombie process.

Hard to tell, *what* caused the problem and how to circumvent it (solving looks close to impossible).